# Same exception for different use case - boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

Using boto3 IAM, i am trying to deactivate MFA device attached to a specified user. I came across few exceptions which i need to handle.

I am passing the UserName during runtime.

1- passing already disabled UserName during runtime

```
python mfa.py John 

botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException: An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the DeactivateMFADevice operation: MFA Device invalid for user.
```

2. Passed incorrect UserName

```
python mfa.py John.d  

botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException: An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the DeactivateMFADevice operation: The user with name John.d cannot be found.
```

How to handle both error, since both exceptions are a part of

`botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchEntityException`

How can i handle the both in different exceptions so that i can

> print("MFA is already disabled")

OR

> print("Invalid UserName")

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by iterating through the exception response dictionary.

Try:

```
 except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException as e:
      print(dir(e))
```

You can find the set of value that can be passed to handle the exception:

> ['MSG_TEMPLATE', '**cause**', '**class**', '**context**',
>   '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**',
>   '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**', '**hash**',
>   '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**',
>   '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**',
>   '**setattr**', '**setstate**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
>   '**subclasshook**', '**suppress_context**', '**traceback**',
>   '**weakref**', '_get_retry_info', 'args', 'operation_name',
>   'response', 'with_traceback']

Above case can be handled by the following method :

```
 except client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException as e:

   if e.response['Error']['Message'] == 'MFA Device invalid for user.':

       print('#something')

   elif e.response['Error']['Message'] == 'The user with name {} cannot be found.'.format(UserName):

       print('#something')
```

Hence handled the exception.